# Referenciar dll dinamicamente C#

Tags: c#, oracle, reflexão

Durante o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação que ira se conectar em banco de dados de diferentes versões, surgiu uma duvida se é possivel carregar a dll baseando-se na versão selecionada pelo usuário.

Exemplo: Iremos ter duas versões do `Oracle 11g e 12c` onde cada versão possui sua dll, o problema é que não estou conseguindo referenciar as duas no projeto sem que gere erro de compilação.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0433  The type 'OracleCommand' exists in both 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' and 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'   DataSetMaker    C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\VSB\Desenvolvimento\DataSetMaker\Controller\Connection.cs    60  Active
```

Existe alguma forma de referenciar elas dinamicamente baseando em radio button onde o usuário selecionaria qual versão deseja utilizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> surgiu uma duvida se é possivel carregar a dll baseando-se na versão
>   selecionada pelo usuário

Sim é possível, porem se você carregar uma dll por `reflection`, tudo que você fizer, terá que ser feito por `reflection`.

Exemplo:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Temp\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll");
var oracleConnectionType =  assembly.GetType("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection");
var connectionInstance = assembly.CreateInstance(oracleConnectionType.FullName);
```

e assim vai... Isso acaba tornando seu código muito complexo e difícil de dar manutenção.

> Existe alguma forma de referenciar elas dinamicamente baseando em
>   radio button onde o usuário selecionaria qual versão deseja utilizar?

Bom, é possível carregar as duas dll ao mesmo tempo e criar métodos específicos para cada uma delas.

O primeiro passo é referencia-las em seu projeto, mas atenção, elas não podem ter o mesmo nome.

O segundo passo é definir um alias para cada um delas:

[image: Deinifir alias para sua dll]

Em uma delas defina o alias para `OnzeG` e para a outra `DozeC`.

O terceiro passo é referenciar esses alias em seu código, acima dos `usings`:

```
extern alias DozenoveI;
extern alias OnzeG;
```

Depois disso, crie seus métodos referenciando todos os tipos com seus alias específicos, colocando-os na frente do método da seguinte forma

```
alias::Type
```

Exemplo:

```
public DataTable ExecutarCom11g(string connectionString, string query)
{
    using (OnzeG::Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection conn = new OnzeG::Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        OnzeG::Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand oracleCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
        oracleCommand.CommandText = query;

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        OnzeG::Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader reader = oracleCommand.ExecuteReader();
        dataTable.Load(reader);

        return dataTable;
    }
}

public DataTable ExecutarCom12c(string connectionString, string query)
{
    using (DozeC::Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection conn = new DozeC::Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        DozeC::Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand oracleCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
        oracleCommand.CommandText = query;

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        DozeC::Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader reader = oracleCommand.ExecuteReader();
        dataTable.Load(reader);

        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

Depois disso é só encapsular os métodos em uma classe e chama-los quando o for conveniente:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=banco;User ID=usuario;Password=senha;";
string query = "select 1 from dual";

BancoDeDados conectorBancoDeDados = new BancoDeDados();
var resultado11g = conectorBancoDeDados.ExecutarCom11g(connectionString, query);
var resultado12i = conectorBancoDeDados.ExecutarCom12c(connectionString, query);
```

Comment: Fantástico, não sabia que era possível definir alias para as referência, muito obrigado deu certo!