# Renomear Dll output C# ProjetoForm VB-2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2019

### O que eu quero é renomear as dll sem perder a referência .

Exemplo : 
 **System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll** para **TRANSPCONSUMIR.System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll** 
Mas quando eu só Renomeio, ele não acha o arquivo .
Quero fazer isso porque , na pasta que vai ficar o projeto já tem umas dll ai da conflito de versão se eu trocar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Gerenciamento de pacotes ta **PackageReference** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Obs/Esclarecimentos:**

1. Não quero mudar o namespace e sim os nomes das dll's de output
2. São vários(2 ou 3) projetos (distintos) na mesma pasta.
3. Só que as dll's desse novo projeto são de versões diferente das que estão na pasta(com os projetos) , tem algum modo de colocar as duas ?
4. Se não tiver, como posso descobrir as versões das dll's que estão na pasta , para dar downgrade nesse novo projeto.

Comment: "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll" isso é uma DLL do framework, não pode renomear isso, o .NET vai buscar isso pelo nome do Assembly.

Comment: então não tem como eu colocar dois "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll" numa pasta que são versões diferentes ?

Comment: tem se elas não tiverem o mesmo nome, mas isso é definido quando adiciona a referencia ao projeto e compila o código, não depois renomeando na pasta

Comment: Veja se essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/424355/referenciar-dll-dinamicamente-c/424455#424455) te ajuda.

Comment: Gerenciamento de pacotes ta PackageReference, não tem como colocar alias eu acho .... @BrunoWarmling

Comment: @RicardoPontual "definido quando adiciona a referencia ao projeto e compila o código " como posso fazer isso ... tenho acesso ao projeto .

Comment: @williamsilva já tentou utilizar o [BindingRedirect](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-add-bindingredirect)? Da pra usar duas versões da mesma .dll usando essa técnica.

Comment: Você até pode usar duas versões, mas deveria?

Comment: @BrunoWarmling só é caso eu usasse o packages.config ... como o meu ta packageReference  não é possível ...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo é projetos distintos ... com dll's - versões diferentes , mas que precisam ficar na mesma pasta.